# CommunityToolkit.Maui.Storage.FileSaver does not consider initialPath?

Tags: c#, maui

I used the FileSaver to implement a "SaveAs ..." functionality.
On first usage everything works fine. I can choose a folder and save the file to that folder.

[image]

On second usage change "dname" in debug mode (to another existing folder):

```
string dname = dirname; // to change dname while debugging
var fileSaverResult = await FileSaver.Default.SaveAsync(dname, fileName, stream, ct);
if (fileSaverResult.IsSuccessful)
{
    // ...
}
```

[image]

-> the opened dialog window shows the previous choosen folder.

I use version 5.0.0 of the toolkit with VisualStudio 2022 version 17.5.3 on Windows 10.0.19045 Build 19045

Comment: That is normal behavior with Net Library.  You can specify a default folder.

Comment: @jdweng: How can I set a default folder ? (Properties.Settings.Default.FolderPath is apparently not available for MAUI)

Comment: The FileDialog has a property InitialDirectory

Comment: It worked using Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog but this is not part of MAUI so I had to use

#if WINDOWS
 Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog fileChooser = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
 string dname = dirname;
 fileChooser.InitialDirectory = dname;
#else
 // use FileSaver.Default.SaveAsync ...
#endif